# localization not working when a single string is not found

Tags: ios, localization

I have an app for which I am testing localization in Italian. I have added the `Localized.strings` file and everythings works fine, but when I add a reference in the code to a string which is not localized, ALL the other strings are not localized too. So my question is, a single string not localized messes everything up? Is there a way to fix this (obviously apart from adding the missing string)?

Comment: "[...] apart from adding the missing string" Is there a point of fixing it in any other way? Would you prefer a partially broken localization, with strings in your default localization popping up throughout the app in random places among the largely Italian text?

Comment: the problem is that I have other 6 languages, including Hebrew, and for that one some strings are not translated. And also, finding the missing strings in all 7 languages is not fun...

Comment: "finding the missing strings in all 7 languages is not fun" That is where simple scripts become invaluable. As far as missing strings go, you can insert placeholder strings manually.

Comment: yes of course I could write a simple script, but still it seems stupid that for one single string everything is not working - for example Android doesn't work that way. Anyway, it seems that sometimes it works and sometimes not. Maybe the simulator simply needs to refresh its cache or something like that

Comment: I would regard that as a feature, not as a bug: it would require a lot more testing to find a missing string if the situation were not "all or nothing". Since localization is part of my program's code, I would prefer to be notified of errors early. Moreover, I wish this triggered a compile-time error :-)

Comment: Actually missing keys in Localized.strings shouldn't change anything for the ones already added. You should get the key for the missing ones.